Kitchen layout redesign
Kitchen redesign/layout
Hi all! Any ideas to make this kitchen more functional? I don’t want to give up the bathroom so trying to use the space already there. The oven next to the dishwasher is a double electric wall oven but is only 24 inches and we cook a lot so want a full size oven somewhere. The other spot is a gas burner with cabinet underneath. Thinking to maybe close off an entrance because 3 seems like a lot and eats up the wall space? https://imgur.com/a/NiU19o6
Floor plan isn’t to scale (disregard the measurement) I put it together myself online.
Thank you all!! I truly appreciate it!

Sorry, voting to Close as Opinion based. It is a good question - but not for this particular web site. If you have specifics regarding code (plumbing or electrical or general building code) or "how to do x" then we can answer. But this question, while interesting to contemplate, is simply too subjective to be answered here.

You need to go to a kitchen design house, and not just some random builder.  A good designer should be able to draw you up some plans, and even show you 3-D views, for little or no cost.  But be prepared for some disappointment if you put too many restrictions on them.

A number of years ago we had a kitchen design firm come in to look at what could be done with our existing galley kitchen.  After a brief visit, she said "no matter what we do, you're still going to have a small galley kitchen".  So we ended up swapping the kitchen and dining rooms.
